# Replace first path of URL with new variable in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to, for example, take this URL:

https://www.example.com/en/blah/blah

But replace "en" with a passed variable?

The PHP I have: (below returns URL little like above)

```
'href' => $this->url->link($route, $url)
```

I have the new language variable available with

```
$result['url_code']
```

But not had any luck with replacing the returned link with replacing the first url section with the result variable.

The initial returned URL with the /*/ first part of the url path will change depending on language so need to replace anything in that first part with the variable `$result['url_code']`

Any ideas?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: been playing with str_replace and also http_build_query but not having much luck lol

Comment: 1. add some code that you tried. 2. check on `explode`

Comment: Were any of the provided answers helpful? You should **upvote** _all answers_ that were helpful if you have the reputation to do so, and **mark accepted** the _one answer_ that best answered your question. This will mark the question as "closed," and give you some reputation on the site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information.

Comment: I am aware of marking questions / upvoting etc.. if you see from all my questions i always do this however the solution was not working right for me and awaiting a reply from my comments.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at `parse_url()` to deconstruct the value that you have, and then rebuild it. This is certainly more verbose than it needs to be, but it does the job reliably and will not break on edge cases.

```
<?php
$url = $this->url->link($route, $url);
$url_parts = parse_url($url);

$path_parts = explode("/", $url_parts["path"]);
// there's a leading slash, so [0] is an empty string
$path_parts[1] = $result['url_code'];
$path = implode("/", $path_parts);

$new_url = "$url_parts[scheme]://$url_parts[host]$path";
if (!empty($url_parts["query"])) {
    $new_url .= "?$url_parts[query]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = "Replaced Word" ;
$url = "https://www.example.com/en/blah/blah";
function findFirst($findingWord, $replacingWord, $url) {
    return implode($replacingWord, explode($findingWord, $url, 2));
}
echo findFirst("blah",$result, $url)
```

Before copy this read those

[Implode Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

[explode Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: @Nick Sorry my bad fixed the problem so could get off your vote from my answer please?

Comment: I just need to replace the first part of the path with that variable, it changes you see so cannot really manually do that function to find and replace.... simply want to just replace any content in first part of path with a variable.

Comment: @James i dont get it your question was string replace on specific string like "http://example.com/blah/blah" to "http://example.com/replace/blah" i taking that answering it now it changes? ok

Comment: "
Is it possible to for example take this URL:

https://www.example.com/en/blah/blah

But replace the first folder level with a passed variable?" bruh

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar yes first part would be /{LANG}/sub/rest_of_url - just need to replace the first part of path but yes as you say is correct